Error: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources
I'm trying to run my Android app in Android Studio, but I encounter the following error:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.2')
  Searched in the following repositories:

Gradle Central Plugin Repository
at Program.execute(Unknown Source)

at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$initAction$6(GradleModelFetchAction.java:184)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:73)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:61)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.initAction(GradleModelFetchAction.java:183)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.doExecute(GradleModelFetchAction.java:138)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$execute$1(GradleModelFetchAction.java:103)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:73)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:61)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$execute$2(GradleModelFetchAction.java:102)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.withOpenTelemetry(GradleModelFetchAction.java:113)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$execute$3(GradleModelFetchAction.java:101)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.util.GradleExecutorServiceUtil.withSingleThreadExecutor(GradleExecutorServiceUtil.java:18)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.execute(GradleModelFetchAction.java:100)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.execute(GradleModelFetchAction.java:36)

Here are the relevant parts of my build.gradle.kts files:
Project-level build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.0.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.21" apply false
}

Module-level app/build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt") // For annotation processing
}

Gradle Wrapper Properties (gradle-wrapper.properties):
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip

settings.gradle.kts:
rootProject.name = "MyActualAppName"
include(":app")

Note: The project name is not real.
When I used com.android.application:8.7.1, org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:2.0.21 and ran the AGP upgrade assistant:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.7.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.7.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

I've  invalidated caches and restarted Android Studio. I'm using Android Studio Ladybug (2024.2.1 Patch 1). What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The first error message seems to be cut off just when it gets interesting. Can you add the missing parts? Please also post your settings.gradle. Also, the versions you use are pretty old. Have you tried the current versions com.android.application:8.7.1 (for Ladybug Patch1) and org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:2.0.21? And what happens if you run the AGP upgrade assistant?

It seems the settings.gradle.kts is missing the most important parts, namely the repositories where the artifacts referenced in the other gradle files can be found.
When creating a new project in Android Studio the settings.gradle.kts that is automatically created along the way looks like this:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "MyActualAppName"
include(":app")

I don't know why most of it is missing for you, but adding it should fix the issues you have.
